# Download and upload a file from a remote url without saving to HDD in php cURL

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, telegram-bot

Im writing two telegram bots and i need to send a photo/voice from one to another.
as written in the documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) you can either pass a url or post the file using multipart/form-data.
Now i can get a link to the image sent to the first bot, which is something like this:

```
api.telegram.org/file/bot<Token>/photos/file_6.jpg
```

from telegram. but weirdly telegram wouldn't accept that link as an image url. if you open it, your browser would show a save dialog instead of showing the image. (anyone know why ?)

so i decided to do it this way:

first i download the file and save it to disk:

```
$json = file_get_contents(API-URL . "/getFile?file_id=" . $contentOrID);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$path = (string)$json['result']['file_path'];
if (!file_exists(FILE-HOST-URL . "/" . $path)) {
    file_put_contents("photos/" . $path, file_get_contents(FILE-HOST-URL . "/" . $path));
}
```

then i Post it:

```
$url = API-URL. '/SendPhoto';
$postfields= array(
    'chat_id' => $ChatID,
    'photo' => new CURLFile(realpath("photos/" . $path)),
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$log = curl_exec($ch);
```

which works fine but its slow because of writing/reading from HDD.
is there any way i can do this on the fly without saving to hard drive ?
i tried these but non worked:

```
        $postfields = array(
        'chat_id' => $ChatID,
        'photo' => file_get_contents(FILE-HOST-URL . "/" . $path)
    );
// then post the above using curl
```

or downloading the file using cURL and passing the curl_exec() return value to 'photo' in $postfields;

Comment: does no one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

ok you cannot Send any message type between bots according to telegram [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

So you cannot send Message from one telegram bot to another

Comment: I'm not trying to send messeage between bots. I'm trying to download the file and send it to another bot. Which is like sending new messages.

Comment: @MajeedAskari it does not matter you cannot send file or message or any thing between two or more bots if you want do so you can use CLI bots library like theleton in [python](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) or Madelineproto in [php](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto)